# Why can i store far more files in a Document Center than in a regular team site?

Tags: capacity-planning

In a regular site the recommendations of Microsoft tells me not to store more than 200 GB in one SiteCollection in one Content Database.

But if I create a "Docment Center"-site I'm allowed to create an 'unlimited' site collection.

The only requirements listed, in order to be able use large (>200GB site collections), are the hardware specs and the skill level of the DBA. And the requirement for the 'Document Center' or 'Record Center' template.

> SharePoint Server 2010 sites must be based on **Document Center** or **Records Center** site templates.

What makes the "Document Center" site template so special that unlimited sizing is allowed?

Is there a technical difference? Compared with a blank or teamsite?

**Ref:**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#ContentDB

Answer (score 0):

The line you quote is in a section specifically describing document archive scenarios, where the site must be one of those two templates along with other restrictions, not a general case for Document Center or Records Center sites being unlimited.

Comment: So, what is so special about those templates that only those two templates can be used in the unlimited archive scenario?